# display:inline not working in IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I am currently developing [www.stopsweats.org](http://www.stopsweats.org)

The menu needs to be horizontal. I have tried using `display:inline` for the `li` , `ul` and even the `div` tag but in IE8 it does not seem to do anything.

Firefox and Chrome are being good to me as usual.

I have tried and tried but is there something I have missed out? Please advise.

Comment: You'll have to post the relevant code here if you want any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `float:left` to save the time need to make `display:inline` work with IE.